# JavaScript typewriter backspace effect

Tags: javascript

I got this code from w3s https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_typewriter and I can't figure out how to backspace letters after its done typing. I've tried to decrement I but that didn't work either. Also, how can I add a delay so the backspace effect doesn't start immediately after?

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
  
  if(i >= txt.length){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML -= txt.charAt(i);
    i--;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot use math operator `-` to delete string character. You need to reassign the value with the end result.

Comment: Can I get a demo, please?

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose did not work

Comment: var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;
var reversedelay=1000
var forwards=true;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length&& i>=0) {
    forwards? i++:i--;
     
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt.sbstring(0,i)
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
  
  if(i >= txt.length && forwards)
     forwards = false;
     i--;
    setTimeout(reverseDelay, speed);
  }

  }

Comment: Sorry,  I'm on my phone :) hard to type etc. Sorry about the wrong comment. The key is to use substring().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `boolean` value (true or false) to keep track if you are backspacing or not. If you are not, you want to increment `i` if you are backspacing then you want to decrement `i`. Here I have used `.substring` to get a portion of the string from index 0 up to a given index.

See example below:

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;
var backspace = false;

var outputElem = document.getElementById("demo"); // get element when page loads
function typeWriter() {
  outputElem.textContent = txt.substring(0, i);

  if (i > txt.length) backspace = true;
  if (i == 0) backspace = false;
  i = i + (backspace ? -1 : 1);
  setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
}
```

```html
<h1>Typewriter</h1>
<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

If you want to stop the loop completely (after the backspace) you can add a condition to the `setTimeout` function call. Moreover, you can give a `delay` between the typing and the backspacing:

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;
let delay = 25;
var backspace = false;

var outputElem = document.getElementById("demo");
function typeWriter() {
  outputElem.textContent = txt.substring(0, i);

  if (i > txt.length + delay) backspace = true;
  if (i == -1) backspace = false;
  i = i + (backspace ? -1 : 1);
  if(i != -1) setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
}
```

```html
<h1>Typewriter</h1>
<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```